# What should I add to a regular expression to remove punctuation marks that appear more than 1 time?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a regular expression that will remove letters of another language and punctuation marks that occur more than 1 time.

To remove the letters from another language here is the usual expression:

```
st = test.replaceAll("[^ a-zA-z0-9]" ,  "");
```

But i don't understand what should i add to it so that it removes not all punctuation marks and spaces ,but only those that occur more than 1 time:
 `String test = new String("agagahh,,,mvf ....      AJFKL  ???");`

I will be glad to help

Input : `"agagahh,,,mvf ....      AJFKL  ???"`

Output:`"agagahh,mvf . AJFKL ?"`

Comment: Can you provide sample input string and sample output string.

Comment: @Unmitigated it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first remove all characters that are not alphanumeric or one of the accepted punctuation marks. Then, you can use a capturing group to match a punctuation mark followed by at one or more of the same punctuation mark, to be replaced by a single punctuation mark.

```
String str = "agagahh,,,mvf ....      AJFKL  ???";
String res = str.replaceAll("[^ a-zA-z0-9.?,]", "").replaceAll("([ .,?])\\1+", "$1");
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to interrupt you again, if you're still here. And is it possible to add here that duplicate newline character are also removed ?

Comment: @Alpharius Something like `String res = str.replaceAll("[^ a-zA-z0-9.?\n,]", "").replaceAll("([ .,?\n])\\1+", "$1");` should work.